# ACF Post Object in admin page not working after wordpress upgade

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have recently update my wordpress to 5.0.1 in my current wordpress setup.

I have use ACF | Pro - Advanced Custom Fields for developing.

**After upgrade wordpress Post object in Acf is not working.The options in select dropdown is empty.**

The current version of acf is 5.3.10 , which I can not upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to downgrade your Wordpress Version to a previous Version.

On the plugin-site of the "ACF | Pro - Advanced Custom Fields plugin" there is the information that it is only tested up for the version 4.9.9 (Wordpress).

Image shows the Plugin-Version-Data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed32a.png)

You can use the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-downgrade/ for the downgrade of your current version.

(Or you might have to wait for a update of the plugin)

Hope this information could help you in some way.

Comment: Any other option?

Comment: Downgrading, upgrading, of bug fixing are the only options. I doubt you're going to be easily able to figure out what the bug might be and if you don't want to downgrade WP then the only option left is to update to the latest version of ACF v5.7.8. It's free and the paid version is $18 USD.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/downloads/

Or you could even experiment with the ACF 5.8 beta if you're not risk averse.

Comment: Update to my previous comment. We saw this issue with a client today, upgrading ACF fixed it for them.